# Linux startup local only

Tags: linux, ssh, x-windows

How can I make something run on startup, but only if I'm logged in locally?

Specifically, I have Conky all set up and running on two different machines. I did this by just running it from my `.profile`. The problem is that when I `ssh -X` from one machine to the other, the remote conky covers up the local one, and I don't really want to see it at all. So where do I put the call to conky where it won't run when I log in through SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [autostart specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) to start Conky. Both Gnome and KDE (and possibly other environments) have their own interface for modifying autostart entries.

Comment: Cool, that allowed me to remove it from my .profile